# Rotate image and set rotation

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm struggling with an issue. I have a 3x3 grid filled with images. When you click an image you are able to rotate it clockwise or anti-clockwise. I then set the rotation with `.setrotation` however I also want to animate the movement.

I am using an animator to rotate the image but that does not set the rotation so I do this as well.

```
RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(prevRotation, rotationClockwise, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotate.setDuration(999);
        rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        rotate.setFillAfter(true);
```

The issue I'm facing is once I complete the animation and set the rotation it does another 90' spin. I believe the animator is only triggering the bitmap and the spin is spinning the whole view.

How would I go about solving this issue?

Comment: Hi Boland! Could you add the calls to this method as well? Where and how are you calling it?

Comment: Hi Jorn, It's set to an on click, I'm starting the animation with mImageToRotate.startAnimation(rotate);

ImageView mImagetoRotate = findviewbyID(image[gridposition]);

To set the image I'm doing mImageToRotate.setRotation(rotationClockwise)

Comment: See my answer. Hope that helps! It's maybe easier than using the RotateAnimation class - one line to do the rotation!

Answer (score 0):

How I would solve this is with the animate() method that every View has in Android:

```
viewToRotate.setOnClickListener(clicked -> {
    final float rotation = 90f; // Specify your rotation here
    viewToRotate.animate().rotationBy(rotation).setDuration(999).start();
});
```